# ag-grid ICellRendererAngularComp vs. AgRendererComponent: Which one should I use?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm using ag-grid-angular and need to make custom cell renderer.

In examples of ag-grid angular document, cell renderers implement `ICellRendererAngularComp`.
But I also found some other examples implementing `AgRendererComponent`.
So I have tried both of them and they are working clearly.

My question is, which interface should I implement to create custom cell renderer?

I cannot find any other codes that only exports these interfaces in ag-grid project like this:

```
export interface ICellRendererAngularComp extends ICellRenderer, AgFrameworkComponent<ICellRendererParams> {
}

...

export interface AgRendererComponent extends ICellRendererAngularComp {
}
```

It seems `AgRendererComponent` is more high-level interface, but examples in ag-grid document are using `ICellRendererAngularComp`...
Can anyone at least tell me differences between them?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the difference between both, but I have used ICellRendererAngularComp for developing custom renderers, which is also the recommended option per Ag Grid documentation:

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/

Comment: Thanks, but I just wanna know the difference. I 'm using ICellRendererAngularComp as document says, either.